# Custom ArrayAdapter with no List type parameter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to create my own **ArrayAdapter** calling just the super constructor that has only 2 parameters, the context and the resource layout id.
The problem is that the **getView** method is never called if I use that constructor, but if I use the other constructors were I pass a List object parameter or an array, it will call my **getView** method.
I tried to override the **isEmpty** method and still nothing, also this method is not called either.

Is there any way to make sure the **getView** method is called just using the super constructor with 2 parameters (context and resource layout id) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post some example code

Comment: Add your code.What have you tried?

Comment: in ArrayAdapter constructor method handle size of your list, if you don't , pass your list to constructor getView not called

Comment: Then what is the point of having a constructor were you can only pass the context and the resource layout id if you need to pass an array or a List object so he can determinate the size of the listview?

Is there any way on how can I bypass this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not passing a List to the super class when using the two-parameter constructor, you'll need to override the `getCount()` method to return the size of your List. Otherwise, the AdapterView will think there are zero items, and will not attempt to call `getView()`. For example:

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return list.size();
}
```